# if delegates can't be overloaded, then how do 'Func' and 'Action' have 16 overloads?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, overloading

I've been learning delegates (in C#), and all of the articles I've read say that delegates can't be overloaded (unlike methods).
But when I was using 'Func' and 'Action' methods (which are .NET built-in delegates), I noticed that they have been overloaded:

[image]

How is it possible?

Comment: You mix `overload` and `override`, I think

Comment: @mjwills when you create an overload for a delegatem, you get an error: "The type 'YouClass' already contains a definition for 'DelegateName'"

Comment: the term "overload" is overloaded; it is very meta, and has overloaded many developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a single delegate type that contains more overloads. You can however have several delegate types with the same name but with a different number of generic parameters such as `Func` and `Action`.

This is different for methods overloads, overloads can specify the same number of parameters with different types, multiple delegates types must have different number of generic parameters to be valid

So this is invalid

```
delegate void A();
delegate void A(int d);
```

but this is valid:

```
delegate void A();
delegate void A<T>(T d);
```

Also the different delegate types that have the same name are not compatible, they are essentially different types that just happen to share a name.

Comment: non-generic version of 'Action' delegate has been overloaded too

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi The naming for the tooltip is unfortunate, but it is not a method overload, they are different types

Comment: It is a fringe case where you could or could not call it "overload". There are multiple delegate variables called "Action". The Compiler has to make the same judgement call wich of those call, as it would with *conventional* Overloads of named Functions. So i guess for the sake of their sanity, the Compiler developers just decides "treat multiple delegates with the same name like you would Overloads for intellisense". Wich unfortunately means it is called an overload in the Tooltip.

Answer (score 5):

Overloading here is being used in a euphemistic manner.

What it's actually telling you here is that there are 16 types, which all happen to be delegate types and all share the same name. The fact that they take different numbers of generic parameters mean that there's no actual relationship between these types.

The overloading terminology is being used because delegate types often are used in contexts in which they resemble methods and, *if* they were methods rather than delegates (and were in the same containing type) they would be overloads.